# Google Apps Script - Modifying Calendar UI & Behavior

Tags: google-apps-script

We have a client that owns Google Apps Business Edition account and wants to modify the default UI and Behavior of *their* Google Calendar page.

We've done our research on Google Calendar API v3 and its features to interact with the Google Calendar service.

So what we'd like to know is:

1) We know that we can't modify Calendar's UI or behavior using it, but we wonder if Google Apps Scripts provides hook methods to interact with the Calendar.For example, when you create an event from the UI.

2) It is possible to add widgets to Spreadsheet, as in `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().show(app)` Is it possible to add widgets to the Calendar UI in the same manner?

3) Do Google Apps Business Edition accounts count with any extra features for Google Apps Scripts as Calendar API v3 does?

We're new to this product as you can see; so let me apologize in advance for the newbie questions.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Yes. Have a look at https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_calendar for details

2) NO. It is not possible to add widgets to your Calendar interface.

3) The only difference between a consumer and Apps for Business account are the quota limits and some minor features dealing with user identification.

Comment: Hi Srik, thanks for your timely response. 

With regards to 1), I've seen there are Calendar creation methods offered by the Calendar class but we need something else. We need to subscribe our application to the action triggered by the "Save" action in the UI.

Do you consider that somehow possible?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you can do is write a script that monitors the calendar for new events (or existing events modified). I've written scripts in the past that did things like synchronize between a calendar and a spreadsheet. So, thats the closest you can come to a hook.