# Add a sidebar to Google Calendar with Google App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, calendar, google-calendar-api

I would like to add an integration to my team's calendar using Google App Script. It would really best to integrate the new menu into the UI of the calendar.

Ideally something like what is possible docs, sheets and forms:

```
 // Display a sidebar with custom HtmlService content.
 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
     .createHtmlOutput('<p>A change of speed, a change of style...</p>')
     .setTitle('My add-on');
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(htmlOutput);

 // Display a sidebar with custom UiApp content.
 var uiInstance = UiApp.createApplication()
     .setTitle('My add-on');
 uiInstance.add(uiInstance.createLabel('The photograph on the dashboard taken years ago...'));
 SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(uiInstance);
```

from https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showsidebaruserinterface

However, [CalendarApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-app) does not appear to have a `.getUi()` method to work with.

Is there some other way to attach a sidebar to a Google CalendarApp?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Apps Script - Modifying Calendar UI & Behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109208/google-apps-script-modifying-calendar-ui-behavior)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not currently possible using Google Apps Script. However, you can modify the Calendar UI by writing a Chrome Extension that injects custom UI elements into the Calendar page's DOM object.

Comment: Thanks, that is unfortunate. A lot of Google's offerings have some strange inconsistencies.